# Is Viburnum opulus 'Roseum' attractive to bees?

Tags: bee-attractive

Is [Viburnum opulus 'Roseum'](https://landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/plants/viburnum-opulus-var-opulus-roseum) attractive to bees and other pollinators?

This cultivar has gorgeous, but sterile [flowers](https://www.plantopedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/viburnum-opulus-gemeiner-schneeball-4326-1068x712.jpg), so I am puzzled if it produces nectar or pollen at all, which would make it desirable for bees.

There is a [blog post](https://www.rosybee.com/blog/2018/8/sterile-plants-for-bees) that claims that some plants with sterile flowers are attractive to bees (their flowers produce nectar, but not seed). The plants mentioned are:

- Geranium rozanne
- Helenium ‘Sahins early flower’
- Lavundula ‘Eidelweis’
- Agastache ‘Blue boa’
- Erysimum ‘Bowles mauve’

But Viburnum opulus 'Roseum' is not among them. (It may be not considered in the study altogether.)

So...?